# eclipse juno SVN : language

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-juno

I just installed SVN in my new eclipse juno with marketplace.
Everything went well, except the fact that all the options are in French (my windows and system may be configured in french, maybe thats the reason).

How can I change the installed language for the SVN? Do i need to reinstall it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding "-nl en_us" to eclipse shortcut ( there is other ways to change the language for more informations see http://svn.haxx.se/subusers/archive-2006-01/0180.shtml )

Hope this can help

Answer (score 3):

Another way is just to uninstall the localization plugin for subversive:

Steps to follow:
Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details

Select Subversive Localization and just uninstall it (you will then need to restart Eclipse).